# Magento 2.4.3 maintenance page only works for admin

Tags: magento2

When I put Magento into maintenance mode, it only works for Admin.
The frontend homepage still displays as normal.
Any ideas whay this might be?
Thank you
Andy

Comment: check for varnish

Comment: Hi Murtuza
Varnish is running.
If I stop it, I get bad gateway error

Comment: clear varnish cache

Comment: Ah ok I'll tray that thanks